# how to create a button on a tab bar on xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, tabbar, xcode9

I want to add a button on the tab bar. I have created a tab bar using story board with four view controllers,actually I have used tabbed application.Now I wanted to add a button on the center of tabBar as shown in image [tabBar with button at the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngT1P.png),programmatically in a appdelegate.swift file. I dont know how to add button on tab Bar when you created tab Bar using storyboard.I don't know how to get reference of tabBar that is created using story board on appdelegate.swift file ,I have search quiet a lot but get nothing.
I am new to iphone development and any help would greatly help me.
I am using xcode 9 so pl tell me according xcode 9 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

the appdelegate.swift file executes before any storyboard starts loading so you can not access to storyboard objects. but you can create your tab bar object programmatically in your appdelegate file, before your app delegate class. it will be created globally. then you can do anything to your tab bar object in func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool method. 
after all these you can add your tab bar object to your storyboard in viewDidLoad method.
but creating global variables are not recommended.

Comment: can I get a reference of tab bar that is created using story board in a viewDidLoad method. If yes then can you share some lines code with me.

Comment: `code` 
class controller: UIViewController {
 
 @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!
 
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  
  tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(name: “sth”)
 }
}
`code`
you should make this viewController class as your storyboards view controller, in identity inspector. then connect the @IBOutlet to your tab bar and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically its not a button, just using image, You have to add using tabbarcontroller.tabbar to add subview on center by framing or constraint.From framing x will be `self.tabbar.frame.size.width/2 - mycenterimage.frame.size.width/2`  for image.
You just have to implement tabcontroller delegate. 

`optional public func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool`

and return No for that index and do what ever you want.

Comment: Just get instance of tabcontroller then "tabVar.delegate = self; then override this in simalar controller or object public func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool{.if (viewController == centerViewControllerObject) return false; else return true; }